# mutliple controller calls in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm fairly new to asp.net MVC3. I followed the link below

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2011/05/02/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-3-application.aspx

it all works fine except my MVC controllers' constructors are being invoked more than one time or may be i didn't notice this behavior before. is there anyone who experienced any such thing or am i missing out something here big time.

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to supply more information.  What do you mean by "invoked more than one time"?  How, when, what are the steps?  How are you measuring this?  Do you mean the constructor is invoked for every request?  If that's the case, then yes that's normal.  Controllers are created new for each request.

Comment: @MystereMan Controllers are created new for each request thats what I believe to but I can't figure out why constructor of every controller no matter what controller and what action I'm trying to access [mainly through changing the URL for a get request] is hit multiple times as I've set breakpoint there and can see my breakpoint being hit more than one time that is per request. Let me know if you know any further details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the browsers Javascript Console (Chromes is very good for this) to make sure that only 1 request is being sent to the controller. You may have a piece of Javascript calling it or maybe a bad url link resolving back to the controller.

Comment: public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
    filters.Add(new LogonAuthorize());  //<<<this seems to be causing the problem but i don't know why
    filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}

meantime i try chrome

Comment: I've also checked it with firebug couldn't figure out chrome js console. There are many get requests but only One to the Controller, but still Controller's constructors is hit more than once. thanks

Comment: @user1162274 - what is LogonAuthorize?  This is not a standard filter, so i would look at the code for that.

Comment: @MystereMan the code was what I shared the link for. You didn't bother looking into it so let me paste it all here. 

`code`
public class LogonAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute {
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) {
         if (!(filterContext.Controller is AccountController))
             base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
     }
}
`code`

This is the LogonAuthorize. if you have any standard implementation blog then do share. Thanks